# Javascript onscroll function not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, onscroll

I am trying to add a `class` to a `id` when the user scrolls past 25 pixels. I am unsure why but the function is not firing after I school. Any help as to why would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```js
window.onscoll = function() {
  showArrow()
};

function showArrow() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 25 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 25) {
    document.getElementById("hide_Arrow").className = "show";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("hide_Arrow").className = "";
  }
}
console.log(arrow);
```

```css
#arrow {
  position: relative;
  height: 270px;
  display: block;
  margin: -20px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#hide_Arrow {
  height: 0px;
  margin: -200px 00px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#hide_Arrow.show {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="hide_Arrow">
  <img id="arrow" src="media/Arrow_down.png" alt="Arrow Down">
</div>
```

Comment: What is arrow in `console.log(arrow);`? window.onscroll may be overwritten, use addEventListener() instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo.

Change this:

```
window.onscoll = function(){showArrow()};
```

For this:

```
window.onscroll = showArrow;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have also faced same issue and solved while writing code as per below in the JavaScript file...

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
   showArrow()
});

function showArrow() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 25 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 25) {
    document.getElementById("hide_Arrow").className = "show";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("hide_Arrow").className = "";
  }
}
console.log(arrow);
```